# What is the folder structure of Java EE web app when using ANT?

Tags: ant, struts2

I am just a beginner in Java EE.

Could anyone tell me what the folder structure is of a Java web app when using Ant?

Could you also let me know where the JSPs, Struts action classes, and resource property files need to be placed?

Comment: ... The web application folder layout is well-documented, as is Struts 2. Have you considered looking at any of the existing Oracle tutorials and Struts 2 sample applications? Ant has nothing to do with it, it's just a build tool.

Comment: Perhaps he means that when using Maven (instead of Ant) one might have another structure http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/struts-2-blank-archetype.html#Struts2BlankArchetype-StructureDifferenceFromNonMavenProjects

Comment: Totally agreed that is what my intention in specifically mentioning the ANT build tool. Thanks for the URL